# Как выполнить метод после нескольких запросов?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rxjava, rxandroid

*Хотел бы реализовать:* По нажатию кнопки происходит загрузка информации с API и добавление (Если пустая)/обновление (Если заполненная) этой информации в базу данных.

*Более подробно:* Использую `Retrofit` для запросов и БД на `SQLLite`. Насколько я понял, нужно использовать фоновый асинхронный поток после нажатия кнопки и там загружать данные и заполнять\обновлять БД. Много читал похожих вопросов, везде советуют `RxJava`, сидел разбирался в RxJava, принцип понял, как он устроен, но примера для нескольких запросов не нашел.

Думал, сначала что все будет обновляться в UI потоке (приложение все равно не имеет практической ценности без БД), а потом подумал, что пусть оно там само обновляется в фоне, а потом какой-нибудь Toast вылезет, мол удачно все прошло. Так логичнее.

В общем, вот код образно:

```
api.getTransportTypes(JSON).enqueue(new Callback<List<TransportType>>() {...};
api.getMarshes(JSON).enqueue(new Callback<List<Marsh>>() {...};
api.getStops(JSON).enqueue(new Callback<List<Stop>>() {...};
...

Log.d("MainActivity", "Data from Api downloaded.");

UpdateDB();

Log.d("MainActivity", "Data Base updated.");
```

**Вопрос:** Как мне объединить и выполнить все запросы в API, а после, что бы вызвался метод, по окончанию загрузки, например образный - `UpdateDB();`?

Если можно какой-нибудь актуальный пример? С сегодняшними фреймворками? На `RxJava` или может какой-то способ через `AsyncTask`, `Handler`, `Loader`? Или алгоритм, хотя бы подробный (Хотя без кода все равно не понятно будет, наверное).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заюзать rx, как вариант, можно так:

1) Реализовать запросы через `RxJava`

- Добавить `.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())` к `Retrofit.Builder()`
- Поменять методы в сервис интерфейсе `@GET("url") fun getStops(): Flowable<List<Stop`>>

2) Применить `zip` к полученным `flowable`

```
Flowable.zip(api.getMarshes(), api.getStops(), api.getTransportTypes(),
    Function3<List<Marsh>, List<Stop>, List<TransportType>, Triple<List<Marsh>, List<Stop>, List<TransportType>>> { marshes, stops, transportTypes ->
        Triple(marshes, stops, transportTypes)
    })
    .flatMapCompletable { insertToDb(it) }
```

[Zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) отправит запросы параллельно, дождется всех ответов и заэмитит дальше

3) Записать в базу

```
fun insertToDb(triple: Triple<List<Marsh>, List<Stop>, List<TransportType>>): Completable {
    return Completable.fromCallable {
        database.insert(triple.first)
        database.insert(triple.second)
        database.insert(triple.third)
    }
}
```

Если ваша БД поддерживает `rx`, то `Flowable.fromCallable` можно избежать
PS код на `kotlin`

Comment: О, вот это уже интересно, Спасибо!
Не все методы Rx еще изучил, по этому опыта не хватило на такое. 
На Kotlin не писал, не знаю. Но там от Java не далеко, разберусь думаю)
Спасибо еще раз, попробую отпишусь.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как переписать это на Java. Точнее хотелось бы пример не привязанный к БД, а просто любой метод (Не важно что там). Смысл: просто объеденить потоки и после них вызвать метод, ни больше ни меньше. Уже 4 день не выходит ничего :(

Comment: @phlogiston https://paste.ofcode.org/JBxR8mjBJHXSPaGStYXdsg

Comment: Спасибо за наводку! Конечный вариант у меня такой:

Comment: `Flowable.zip(`[Тут перечисляем свои Retrifit-запросы]`,
                this::requestsToArray`[Тут то что будем делать с запросами. Я их объединил в список. Метод возвращает список.]`)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this::doSomethingWithRequests`[В этом методе делаем что хотим с ответами от запросов. Метод void.]`);`

Answer (score 1):

Асинхронный запрос можно легко решить классом AsyncTask а для запросов рекомендую okhttp3. Это все что нужно для решения задачи.
на начала подключаешь okhttp в градле:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
```

Далее создадим интерфейс в которым пропишем действие которые нужно совершить после запроса(если не понял не страшно это реально тяжело понять с первого раза. поймеш по ходу делу):

```
interface Callback {
     public void onSuccess(String result);
     public void onFail();
}
```

после создаешь класс который будет делать ассинхронный запрос:

```
public class AsyncLoad extends AsyncTask<String , String , String> {

private String[] data;
private Callback callback;
// конструктор куда передаем информацию @data и метод который будет срабатывать после запроса @Callback
public AsyncLoad (String[] data , Callback callback){
    this.data = data;
    this.callback = callback;
}


// все что написанно в методе doInBackground будет работать во втором потоке
// не в коем случае не работайте со view элементами внутри метода doInBackground
// Работа со вью должно быть прописано в Callback
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

    // сколько минут будет длиться запрос
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(5 , TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(5 , TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(5 , TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();
    // тело запроса
    // я обычно в data[0] пишу инфу которую отправляю а в data[1] url
    // например data[1] = "http://mydomain.com/load.php"
    FormBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("data" , data[1])
            .build();
    // тут строиться сам запрос, решаеться отправлять пост или гет
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(data[0].concat("delete/pub.php"))
            .post(body)
            .build();
    // ну а тута запуск запроса
    // прошу не путать запуск запроса с запуском класса
    try {
        return client.newCall(request).execute().body().string();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
// все что происходит внутри onPostExecute это происходит в основном потоке
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    if(result == null){
        callback.onFail();
    }
    else{
        callback.onSuccess(result)
    }
}
}
```

и почти все можешь запускать например с таким методом:

```
        public void loadData(){
        String[] data = new String[2];
        data[0] = "http://mydomain.com";
        // любую строку обычно json все используют но можно и свое
        data[1] = jsonObject.toString;

        Callback callback = new Callback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result){
                TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
                txt.setText(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail(){
                Toast.makeText(context , "load error" , Toast.LONG).show();
            }
        };
        new AsyncLoad(data , callback).execute();
    }
```

Полностью робочей вариант. Меня это еще не подвадила

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, конечно, вариант интересный, но не то что я бы хотел. Тут решение без Retrofit и после придется парсить данные. К тому, же коллбек выполняется, как я понял, после таймаута. Я не хочу ждать определенное кол-во времени, а выполнять метод сразу по окончанию всех запросов.
Да и кода много и не особо читаемо и масштабируемо.

Хотел бы именно продолжить свой вариант, а не все переписывать.

Comment: @Александр Попов  timeout это время которое он будет пытаться загрузить если плохая сеть. Если же сеть хорошая то он не заставит вас ждать. Калбэк сработает сразу же после того как получишь ответ от сервера. К тому же ретофарит работает на основе okhttp опять же. А парсить да может и не удобно но все так сказать под контролем и Вобще система более гибкая поняв которую можно решить не мало задач из ООП. Лучше на начала научиться создавать такой запрос а потом уже изучать такую штуку как ретофарит. Выбор за вами.

Comment: Окей, насчет таймаута понял, спасибо за пояснение. Я знаю, что ретрофит работает на okhttp, понимаю, что так гибко и все контролируется, я просто этот этап в понимании уже прошел, делал такие запросы :)
Я принципиально хочу решить задачу через ретрофит и прочие фреймворки. Для опыта)